# What's a proper way to call a chain of methods that modify an instance attribute?

Tags: design-patterns, python, method-chaining

I've got an Algorithm class whose responsibility is to find if a given word is in a list of words.

As part of doing that, the algorithm first has to lowercase the words, remove punctuation, and remove any stopwords. Then, finally, the algorithm tries to find the given word in the cleaned list via the `find_word` method.

As you can see in the code, I have split everything in small methods to avoid having one big method. However, I am not sure what's the proper way to call those methods. I am calling all them inside the `find_word` method one after the other, but that smells like a bad design to me. How do I do this the right way?

```
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')

class Algorithm:

    def __init__(self, words: list):
        self.words = words

    def _lower(self):
        # Lowercase all words of the list
        self.words = [word.lower() for word in self.words]

    def _remove_punctuation(self):
        # Remove punctuation from all words of the list
        punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)  # creates dict of {33:None, 34:None, etc}
        self.words = [words.translate(punct_dict) for words in
                     self.words]

    def _remove_stopwords(self):
        # Remove stopwords from list such as in, at, who, etc.
        self.words = [word for word in self.words if word not in stopwords]

    def find_word(self, user_word):
        # Find if the user given word is in the cleaned list
        self._lower()
        self._remove_punctuation()
        self._remove_stopwords()
        if user_word in self.words:
            return user_word

class Chatbot:

    def answer(self, user_word):
        algorithm = Algorithm(['Rabbit', 'Horse', 'turtle'])
        return algorithm.find_word(user_word)


chatbot = Chatbot()
print(chatbot.answer('horse'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obviously bad thing in your design is that if you call `find_word` multiple times on the same `Algorithm` instance, you are duplicating the preparation work on the wordlist.

That can be remedied by calling `_lower`, `_remove_punctuation` and `_remove_stopwords` from `__init__`.

Apart from that, you might want to do some preprocessing on the `user_word` as well, so that `find_word('hORSE')` would also work, and maybe even `find_word('!horse!')`.